# My S3 doesn't have Auto screen off/on option

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, settings, screen

Hi I'm trying to look for Auto screen off/on during calls but I could not locate it. It's not on my Call Settings. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a case? please DO NOT Block the upper part of the screen because the proximity sensor that turns the screen off when on call is located there. There is no option in settings because it is fully automatic